# Entity Framework ExecuteDelete does not work as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I encountered a weird problem with the new Entity Framework Core 7 `ExecuteDelete` feature.

Context: `Bar` holds a list of `Foo` (`Bar` as a 1 to n relation to `Foo`):

```
public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }

    public Bar bar { get; set; }
}
```

I call

```
dbContext.Foo.Where(F => F.Id == <someID>).ExecuteDelete();
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Then in another class (immediately after this call), I run:

```
Bar bar = dbContext.Bar
                   .Where(b => <condition>)
                   .Include(b => b.Foo)
                   .First();
```

In `bar`, the deleted `Foo` from the previous call still exists. The `dbContext` is defined as a singleton.

Those solutions work fine:

```
dbContext.Foo.Remove(<instanceFoo>);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
Bar.Foo.Remove(<instanceFoo>);
dbContext.Update(Bar);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Can somebody explain to me what´s happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the way Entity Framework tracks changes to entities in memory.

When you execute `dbContext.Foo.Where(F => F.Id == <someID>).ExecuteDelete()` EF marks the matching `Foo` entity as deleted and removes it from the database when `dbContext.SaveChanges()` is called. However, it doesn't remove the deleted entity from memory.

When you subsequently query for a `Bar` entity and include its related `Foo` entities using `dbContext.Bar.Where(b => <condition>).Include(b => b.Foo).First()`, EF loads the `Bar` entity and its related `Foo` entities from the database and tracks them in memory.
Since EF didn't remove the deleted Foo entity from memory in the previous step, it's still present in the `Bar` object's `Foo` collection.

The reason why the alternative solutions that you posted work is because they remove the deleted `Foo` entity from memory explicitly.
In the first solution, calling `dbContext.Foo.Remove(<instanceFoo>)` marks the entity as deleted and removes it from memory, so it's not included in subsequent queries.
In the second solution, calling `Bar.Foo.Remove(<instanceFoo>)` removes the entity from the Foo collection of the Bar object in memory and marks it as modified, so EF removes it from the database when `dbContext.SaveChanges()` is called.

To avoid this issue, you could reload the `Bar` entity and its related `Foo` entities from the database after executing the delete operation, using something like:

```
dbContext.Entry(bar).Collection(b => b.Foo).Load();
```

This will reload the `Foo` entities for the `Bar` object from the db and replace the in-memory collection, so the deleted `Foo` entity will no longer be present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You might be correct. After the application restarts the entry is gone. (DbContext gets refreshed in memory). However i took the navigation property Bar executed the load function but the entry is still there

Comment: `int tourId = tourLog.Tour.Id;
            int deltaRows = dbContext.TourLogs.Where(tl => tl.Id == tourLog.Id).ExecuteDelete();
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            Tour tour = dbContext.Tours.First(tour => tour.Id == tourId);
            dbContext.Entry(tour).Collection(t => t.TourLogs).Load();

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            Tour tour2 = dbContext.Tours.First(tour => tour.Id == tourId);`

Tour = Bar, TourLog = Foo, Tour2 still has the deleted tourlog (deltarows was 1) @Alex